# Wikimedia Maps Layer (open street maps) getting 429 error (trouble connecting to ssl with wget)

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, wikimedia

Trying to trace down why The wikimedia map layer is down, wondering if anyone has heard anything.  Google wasn't very helpful

This has been broken since at least yesterday for our maps : https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png

The site is up, trying to find out if they changed how the layers were pulled?

https://maps.wikimedia.org/#4/40.75/-73.96

I used wget and getting this

````
Resolving maps.wikimedia.org... 208.80.154.240
Connecting to maps.wikimedia.org|208.80.154.240|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection.```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It does seem as if your apllication does not support modern TLS protocols but tries to connect with the really old TLS 1.0 that is not supported anymore by wikimedia maps.</strike>

Upgrade your TLS to version 1.2 and you should be fine.

Edit: wikimedia now blocks map access for external users. See https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T245145#5880898

I don't understand why this produces a TLS error, but the likely reason for your problems is the 429 http error code because of wikimedias blocking external projects. You'll need a different tile provider.

Comment: It's already at 

TLS 1.2, AES with 256 bit encryption (High); ECDH with 255 bit exchange

Comment: Also in wget conf? What is your secureprotocol setting in wget?

Comment: TLSv1_2 is what is set

Comment: The quoted error says you are using TLS 1.0. Any proxy in between? On the other hand if you get a HTTP 429 error (as stated in your question title) you are just accessing the tiles too often and got blocked by wikimedia maps. But this should happen after SSL connection imho.

Comment: I edited the answer. Wikimedia started blocking external accesses one week ago.